# How to url-encode special characters in a url

Tags: urlencode, rebol, rebol3

I have a url which contains "!", "@", "#" and the server seems to choke, when these are not urlencoded.

Now Rebol3 seems to not urlencode them itself.

```
>> url: http://test/abc/#def/ghi
== http://test/abc/#def/ghi
```

If I do it manually, the "%" gets encoded, though:

```
>> replace url "#" "%23"
== http://test/abc/%2523def/ghi
```

Any idea on how to encode characters, which are not normally encoded?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking specifically about how to percent-encode data. However, while facing the same problem as yours, I have found how to decode a percent-encoded string, which I found useful too.

Just in case you need a percent-decode function, see [`dehex`](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wdehex.html) for rebol2 and rebol3, as it does the decoding job natively.